# Issues with writing to Resident Model through Site controller to auto generate a new resident for specific site

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

Evening everyone! I am having an issue with my controller, it is returning `undefined method`residents' for nil:NilClass` when i try to render the page.

i am trying to populate a new resident to a specific site.

my sites_controller.rb looks as follows. -- I created the method site_resident to handle this. (thirs method from the top of the page.

```html
    class SitesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :set_site, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /sites
  # GET /sites.json
  def index
    @sites = Site.all
  end

  # GET /sites/1
  # GET /sites/1.json
  def show
  end

  def site_resident
    @resident = @site.residents.new
  end

  # GET /sites/new
  def new
    @site = Site.new
  end

  # GET /sites/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /sites
  # POST /sites.json
  def create
    @site = Site.new(site_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @site.save
        format.html { redirect_to @site, notice: 'Site was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @site }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @site.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /sites/1
  # PATCH/PUT /sites/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @site.update(site_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @site, notice: 'Site was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @site }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @site.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /sites/1
  # DELETE /sites/1.json
  def destroy
    @site.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to sites_url, notice: 'Site was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_site
      @site = Site.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def site_params
      params.require(:site).permit(:call_sign, :address, :unit_number, :city, :prov, :postal_code, :ec1_n, :ec1_t, :ec1_t, :ec2_n, :ec2_t, :ec2_e, :ec3_n, :ec3_t, :ec3_e, :lat, :lng)
    end
end
```

My routes.rb file look like this :

```html
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'home#index'

  resources :residents
   
  resources :sites do
    member do
      get :site_resident
    end
  end
  
  devise_for :users
```

im sure its something small that im overlooking but i cant seem to wrap my head around it. thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `:site_resident` to your array for the `before_action :set_site`.
The line should read:

```
before_action :set_site, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, : site_resident]
```

Comment: thanks so much i figured it was something small! greatly appreciated as soon at the timer runs down ill give you best answer.